# My ionic app sends empty images to Firebase Storage

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-storage

when i send images to Firebase storage it's keep loading and doesn't show anything
and all the images size the same "15 b". It gives me empty images and when I try to open the download URL, it show nothing:

[image: 1]

the HTML

```
<ion-content>

<button class="button" ng-click="selImages()">add</button>

</ion-content>
```

the AngularJS

```
var images = [];
var path = [];
var finimg = [];
var imageblob = [];
var downloadURL = [];

$scope.selImages = function() {
    var options = {
    maximumImagesCount: 2, // only pick one image
    width: 800,
    height: 800,
    quality: 80
  };

    $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
    .then(function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
                images.push(results[i].replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''));


                if ($ionicPlatform.is("android")) {
                    path.push(cordova.file.cacheDirectory);
                  } else {
                    path.push(cordova.file.tempDirectory);
                  }

                finimg.push($cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer(path[i],  images[i]));

                imageblob.push(new Blob([finimg[i]], { type: "image/jpeg" }));

                var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

                 var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' +      images[i]).put(imageblob[i]);

                  // Register three observers:
            // 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
            // 2. Error observer, called on failure
            // 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
            uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
              // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
              // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
              var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
              console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
              switch (snapshot.state) {
                case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                  console.log('Upload is paused');
                  break;
                case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                  console.log('Upload is running');
                  break;
              }
            }, function(error) {
              // Handle unsuccessful uploadsx
              alert("not goood")
            }, function() {
                alert("Saved Successfully!!")
              // Handle successful uploads on complete
              // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
              $scope.downloadURL.push(uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL);
            });
            }
        }
        );



}
```